# How to divide a picture into evenly spaced squares with python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to use PIL and define my own function, which will take an image and a square_size (width or height) as parameters, then divide the image into a series of smaller squares of said size. I don't understand PIL's crop method. It accepts a (top, left, right, bottom). A top left, top right, etc etc system seems much more useful.

Where I', stuck is writing code that can find what these coordinates should be, starting at the origin, given a square size. Any ideas?

Here's what does not work.

```py
def parse_image(source, square_size):
    src = Image.open(source)
    dimensions = src.size
    max_up = int(src.height/square_size)
    max_right = int(src.width/square_size)

    tl = 0
    tr = square_size
    bl = square_size * src.width + 1 
    br = bl + square_size

    test = src.crop((tl,tr,bl,br))
    test.save('test.jpg')
    test.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `square_size` is an int defining the length of each side and that we want more than one image as a result.
Code below is untested but should solve your problem

```
def parse_image(source, square_size): 
    src = Image.open(source)
    width, height = src.size
    image_results = []
    for x in range(0, width, square_size): #
        for y in range(0, height, square_size):
            top_left = (x, y) #left top of the rect
            bottom_right = (x+square_size, y+square_size) #right bottom of the rect
            #the current format is used, because it's the cheapest
            #way to explain a rectange, lookup Rects
            test = src.crop((top_left[1], top_left[0], bottom_right[0], bottom_right[1]))
            image_results.append(test)

    return image_results
```

Let me know if there are any issues!

Edit, I was inspired by a candidate answer, and this solution worked.

```py
def parse_image(source, square_size, print_coords=False):
    src = Image.open(source)
    dimensions = src.size
    print(f"image dimensions: {src.size}")
    max_down = int(src.height/square_size) * square_size + square_size
    max_right = int(src.width/square_size) * square_size + square_size

    tl_x = 0
    tl_y = 0
    br_x = square_size 
    br_y = square_size

    count=0
    for y in range(square_size,max_down,square_size):
        for x in range(square_size,max_right,square_size):
            count +=1
            sample = src.crop((tl_x,tl_y,br_x,br_y))
            sample.save(f"{source[:-4]}_sample_{count}_x{tl_x}_y{tl_y}.jpg")
            if print_coords == True: 
                print(f"image {count}: top-left (x,y): {(tl_x,tl_y)}, bottom-right (x,y): {(br_x,br_y)}")
            tl_x = x
            br_x = x + square_size
        tl_x =0
        br_x = square_size
        tl_y = y
        br_y = y + square_size
```